# Sybase - create filename with date in "output to" filename

Tags: sqlanywhere

Was trying to datestamp the output filename - but keep getting errors -- along the lines of:

```
Select * from Orders
output to 'c:'+ select (CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)) + 'orders.csv'
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Syntax Error: '+' was not expected

Comment: IAnywhere - 11  --- Wanted output filename like 2011-06-22orders.csv

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - sorry for the delay responding UNLOAD SELECT * FROM Orders INTO CLIENT FILE 'c:mydir\todaysdate.csv' this works fine - but you need WRITECLIENTFILE authority - to transfer the data to the client...need to alter some permissions

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem on Sybase 9 - I had to write each procedure / function body inside spearate file named as that procedure. So I had to dynamically create file name using name of each procedure (or function). Below is my solution (works in isql):

```
begin
    declare folder varchar (40);
    declare fileName varchar(60);
    -- folder parameter is our destination path - the 4 backslashes are important here
    set folder = 'c:\\\\test\\\\sql\\\\';
    -- here we are iterating over all procedures / functions
    for p as curs dynamic scroll cursor for 
        Select distinct sysobjects.name
            from sysobjects inner join syscomments
            on sysobjects.id = syscomments.id where sysobjects.type = 'P'
    do
        -- each procedure must be inside separate file named like that procedure
        set fileName =  folder + name + '.sql';
        -- finally, there are answer to original question:
        -- we are exporting data into file, whose name is defined dynamically
        unload select proc_defn from SYS.SYSPROCEDURE where proc_name = name 
            to fileName escapes off;
    end for;
end
```

Comment: It's awesome that you included code in your answer, but would you mind sharing more details on *what this code is doing* and *why* this solved the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just updated my answer by giving some brief description of problem and placing some comments describing each step

Answer (score 2):

`output to` is a dbisql command, so it's interpreted on the client. This means that you can't use expressions for the filename, since they are executed on the server. However you can use the `unload select` statement (which does run on the server) with the `into client file` clause to do what you want.

See docs on the `unload select` statement [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1101/en/dbreference_en11/unload-statement.html%2ad5e49559).

*Disclaimer: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.*